# How to create an array of callables based on a std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, variant, std-variant

How can I create an array of functions that based off a `std::variant` which composed of a few message types, where they are to be decoded from io bytes, so that I can quickly access the right functions based on a mid field from the bytes.

```
struct S1 { constexpr static int MID = 1; };
struct S2 { constexpr static int MID = 2; };
struct S3 { constexpr static int MID = 3; };
struct S4 { constexpr static int MID = 4; };
struct S5 { constexpr static int MID = 5; };

typedef std::variant<S1,S2,S3,S4,S5> MyVariant;


template<class M> void decode(M* output, const std::vector<char>& input)
{
    // generic decoding for everything else
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template<> void decode(S3* output, const std::vector<char>& input)
{
    // speical decoding for S3
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template<> void decode(S5* output, const std::vector<char>& input)
{
    // speical decoding for S5
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

I tried this:

```
using Decode_func = void(void*, const std::vector<char>& input);
constexpr std::array<Decode_func*, std::variant_size_v<MyVariant>> funcs = {};
```

But this doesn't work because the first parameter of `Decode_func` needs to match the exact parameter but in function template, the actual type is unknown. Also how can I fill the `funcs` array in compile time?

What I wanna achieve in the end is like this:

```
std::vector<char> buffer = read(...);
int mid = getMid(buffer);

std::variant_alternative_t<mid, MyVariant> msg;
Decode_func *decoder = funcs[mid-1];  // how can I build and fill funcs from decode functions at compile time

decoder(&msg, buffer);
MyVariant v(msg);
// pass v for processing
```

Comment: Maybe an abstract factory could help? But for me, it is not really sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: `std::variant_alternative_t<mid, MyVariant> msg;` won't work with an int read at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to get from the raw bytes in `input` to a type.
The index template parameter to `std::variant_alternative` must be a compile time constant and the `MID` bytes inside `input` are *not* compile time constants - so you can't use that.

```cpp
MyVariant decode(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {
    if(input.size() < 4) throw std::runtime_error("nope");

    // extract `mid` (use whatever way you use already):
    uint32_t mid = (uint32_t(input[0]) << 24) +
                   (uint32_t(input[1]) << 16) +
                   (uint32_t(input[2]) << 8) + input[3];

    switch(mid) { // lookup the right function to use for decoding
    case S3::MID: return decode<S3>(input);
    case S5::MID: return decode<S5>(input);
    default:        
        MyVariant rv;
        //generic decoding
        return rv;
    }
}
```

Where the `decode` function template and specializations could be:

```cpp
template<class S> MyVariant decode(const std::vector<uint8_t>&);

template <>
MyVariant decode<S3>(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {
    S3 rv; // special decoding for S3
    // ...
    return rv;
}

template <>
MyVariant decode<S5>(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {
    S5 rv; // special decoding for S5
    // ...
    return rv;
}
```

---

---

A second option could be to put the decoding into the constructor of the actual types:

```cpp
struct generic_decoder { 
    generic_decoder(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {} 
};

struct S1 : generic_decoder { constexpr static uint32_t MID = 1; };
struct S2 : generic_decoder { constexpr static uint32_t MID = 2; };
struct S3 {
    constexpr static uint32_t MID = 3;
    S3(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {
        // special decoding for S3
    }
};
struct S4 : generic_decoder { constexpr static uint32_t MID = 4; };
struct S5 {
    constexpr static uint32_t MID = 5;
    S5(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {
        // special decoding for S5
    }
};
```

This would let the lookup and creation part be pretty clean:

```cpp
MyVariant decode(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {
    if (input.size() < 4) throw std::runtime_error("nope");

    uint32_t mid = (uint32_t(input[0]) << 24) + (uint32_t(input[1]) << 16) +
                   (uint32_t(input[2]) << 8) + input[3];

    switch(mid) {
        case S1::MID: return S1(input);
        case S2::MID: return S2(input);
        case S3::MID: return S3(input);
        case S4::MID: return S4(input);
        case S5::MID: return S5(input);
        default: throw std::runtime_error("invalid MID in input");
    }
}
```

---

---

A third, more expensive, version could be to first create the `MyVariant` instance and then use `std::visit` to `decode`. It works, but it's unnecessary since you already know the type you put in the `variant`. Anyway, it could look like this:

```cpp
struct generic_decoder { void decode(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {} };

struct S1 : generic_decoder { constexpr static uint32_t MID = 1; };
struct S2 : generic_decoder { constexpr static uint32_t MID = 2; };
struct S3 {
    constexpr static uint32_t MID = 3;
    void decode(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {
        // special decoding for S3
    }
};
struct S4 : generic_decoder { constexpr static uint32_t MID = 4; };
struct S5 {
    constexpr static uint32_t MID = 5;
    void decode(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {
        // special decoding for S5
    }
};

using MyVariant = std::variant<S1, S2, S3, S4, S5>;
```

And create an array of `MyVariant` with default constructed in instances of your types. You then copy the correct variant by indexing and then `std::visit` to `decode`:

```cpp
MyVariant decode(const std::vector<uint8_t>& input) {
    static const std::array<MyVariant, 5> vs{S1{}, S2{}, S3{}, S4{}, S5{}};

    if (input.size() < 4) throw std::runtime_error("nope");

    uint32_t mid = (uint32_t(input[0]) << 24) + (uint32_t(input[1]) << 16) +
                   (uint32_t(input[2]) << 8) + input[3];

    auto rv = vs.at(mid - 1); // throws if `mid` is invalid
    std::visit([&](auto&& var) { var.decode(input); }, rv);
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You create an array of Callables to create the correct `MyVariant` variant, based on the integer you read at runtime. Then you add an additional specialization for `decode` that accepts `MyVariant` and dispatches to the correct `decode` specialization for the held variant via `std::visit`:

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct S1 { constexpr static int MID = 1; };
struct S2 { constexpr static int MID = 2; };
struct S3 { constexpr static int MID = 3; };
struct S4 { constexpr static int MID = 4; };
struct S5 { constexpr static int MID = 5; };

typedef std::variant<S1,S2,S3,S4,S5> MyVariant;

template <class M>
void decode(M* output, const std::vector<char>& input) {
    // generic decoding for everything else
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template <>
void decode(S3* output, const std::vector<char>& input) {
    // speical decoding for S3
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template <>
void decode(S5* output, const std::vector<char>& input) {
    // speical decoding for S5
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template <>
void decode(MyVariant* output, const std::vector<char>& input)
{
    std::visit([&input](auto out) { decode(&out, input); }, *output);
}

std::array<std::function<MyVariant()>, 5> variantfactory = {
    []{ return S1{}; },
    []{ return S2{}; },
    []{ return S3{}; },
    []{ return S4{}; },
    []{ return S5{}; },
};

int main() {
    // read from buffer
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    int mid = 3;

    auto msg = variantfactory[mid-1]();
    decode(&msg, buffer);
    // pass msg for processing
}
```

```
23 void decode(M*, const std::vector<char>&) [with M = S3]
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bM7YGKheW

Answer (score -1):

This reads *a lot* like you're trying to reinvent virtual inheritance, a feature that C++ already has with classes; no need to use a `std::variant`.

But assuming you have good reason to use `std::variant` instead, your question becomes basically "How do I use the currently active type of a variant as typename, in order to resolve functions", and the answer is: you'll need to write a visitor that, at runtime, makes that type distinction.

`std::visit` allows you to do that. [Cppreference's page on it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) has a workable example, something that's reworkable to

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct S1 {
    constexpr static int MID = 1;
};
struct S2 {
    constexpr static int MID = 2;
};
struct S3 {
    constexpr static int MID = 3;
};
struct S4 {
    constexpr static int MID = 4;
};
struct S5 {
    constexpr static int MID = 5;
};

using MyVariant = std::variant<S1, S2, S3, S4, S5>;

template <class M>
void decode(M* output, const std::vector<char>& input) {
    // generic decoding for everything else
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template <>
void decode(S3* output, const std::vector<char>& input) {
    // speical decoding for S3
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template <>
void decode(S5* output, const std::vector<char>& input) {
    // speical decoding for S5
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    MyVariant s1var;
    S3 s3;
    S5 s5;
    MyVariant s3var(s3);
    MyVariant s5var(s5);
    std::vector<char> inp;
    for (const auto& var : {s1var, s3var, s5var}) {
        std::visit([inp](const auto& out) { decode(&out, inp); }, var);
    }
}
```

([run in Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zMqzGjjnh))

Comment: Thanks it's a little different, I don't have a variant, what I need is first decode the struct from the buffer, then create a `std::variant`. I'm stuck on the 1st step now.

Comment: but then, why are you type-erasing in your `Decode_func`? If you did *not* do that conversion of the specific-type pointer to `void*`, normal argument type-dependent function lookup just works? So, call `decode` with your object directly?

Comment: I don't have the structs or the variant in the beginning, I need to decode it first then create a variant, I just updated my question on what I am looking for.